# Is passing undefined equivalent to passing no argument?

Tags: javascript, arguments, undefined

Curiously,

```
['a', 'b', 'c'].lastIndexOf('b', undefined)
```

returns -1 while the following:

```
['a', 'b', 'c'].lastIndexOf('b')
```

returns 1 (at least on Firefox 65's scratchpad).

I assumed passing `undefined` would have the same result as passing no argument.

However it seems

```
['a', 'b', 'c'].lastIndexOf('a', undefined)
```

does return 0 as expected, which makes me believe my `undefined` gets converted to 0.

I understand the default value of the `index` parameter in `lastIndexOf` points to the last element of the array.
But shouldn't passing `undefined` have the same behaviour as passing no argument?

Comment: `function foo () {return arguments.length}; foo(1) //1; foo(1, undefined); //2` - passing undefined affects `arguments.length` which might change function behavior. And it actually happens with `lastIndexOf`

Comment: @Andrey yes I figured the test was made on arguments.length or I wouldn't understand how this happens. The question remains: does it break javascript's specs if passing undefined gives a different result as passing nothing?

Comment: I don't remember standard by heart, but I believe there's no such spec.

Comment: @Andrey Let me go further: what's the point of having the arguments be ['b', undefined] instead of ['b']?

Comment: @PierreArlaud — Now you're asking people to speculate on the reasoning behind design decisions.

Comment: The default value for the second argument in **lastIndexOf** function is +Infinity which the index to start searching from backwards so passing no arg will start search from the last element then the previous till the first element , and that's is the default behavior but if you pass a null or undefined or anything that will converted to number to start searching from backwards , so passing **undefined** here meaning start searching from 0 and then -1 , but because arrays haven't negative index , **lastIndexOf** will return -1 if the element index is great than zero .

Comment: @PierreArlaud No, I didn't read your last paragraph, sorry. Well, the polyfill at [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/lastIndexOf) clearly states that the second argument, if any, is converted by `Number(arguments[1]);`, which turns your `undefined` to `NaN`. Just after that it has `if (n != n) { n = 0;}`, which checks for `NaN` (the only thing in JS which is not equal to itself), and converts that `NaN` to 0. Well, that's just the polyfill, but the actual browser implementation must be somehow similar, as your test shows.

Answer (score 3):

I previously wrote a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54629104/is-passing-undefined-equivalent-to-passing-no-argument#comment96050852_54629104) explaining that, according to the polyfill at [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/lastIndexOf), the `undefined` as the second argument of `Array.prototype.lastIndexOf` (in the polyfill the parameter named `n`) indeed gets converted to `0` by these steps:

1. `n = Number(undefined)` => converts `undefined` to `NaN`.
2. `if(n != n) n = 0` => checks for `NaN` and converts it to 0.

```js
let n = Number(undefined);
if (n != n) n = 0;
console.log(n);
```

Since this is just the polyfill at MDN it seemed to me that it wasn't worth a proper answer. However, the spec at [ECMA-International](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-array.prototype.lastindexof) says the same about `Array.prototype.lastIndexOf(searchElement[,fromIndex])`:

> If argument fromIndex was passed let n be ToInteger(fromIndex); else let n be len-1.

Where `len-1` is obviously the last index of the array. Then, we have at `ToInteger`:

> 1. Let number be ToNumber(argument).
> 2. ReturnIfAbrupt(number).
> 3. If number is NaN, return +0.

In conclusion, your `undefined` gets converted to `0` and, therefore, passing `undefined` as the second argument of `Array.prototype.lastIndexOf` is different from passing nothing.

**EDIT**

Given your [last comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54629104/is-passing-undefined-equivalent-to-passing-no-argument/54629817?noredirect=1#comment96058004_54629817) I reckon that the cause of your misunderstanding is clear. You see, there is no default parameter here, and this whole issue has nothing to do with it. Let me explain:

As you know, in JavaScript we can pass more arguments than parameters or less arguments than parameters. If we pass too few arguments, the missing parameters are `undefined`. This is easy to show:

```js
function foo(parameter1, parameter2) {
  console.log("parameter 2 is " + parameter2)
};
foo("bar");
foo("bar", undefined);
```

As you can see, passing nothing or passing `undefined` has the same effect. However, this is **not** what's happening here. In the polyfill the function uses the pseudo argument array-like `arguments` to get the second argument, testing for `arguments.length > 1`. Therefore, when you [say](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54629104/is-passing-undefined-equivalent-to-passing-no-argument#comment96053896_54629817)...

> Does undefined count as a passed argument? I thought it didn't.

It does when you take into account the length of the `arguments` array-like object. And, in that case, the difference does matter:

```js
function foo(parameter1, parameter2) {
  if (arguments.length > 1) {
    console.log("parameter 2 is " + arguments[1])
  } else {
    console.log("no second parameter")
  }
};
foo("bar");
foo("bar", undefined);
```

Comment: Hence the question: does undefined count as a passed argument? I thought it didn't

Comment: Yes, it does. Why wouldn't it?

Comment: Hmm this seems to have changed with ES5 and the arrival of default parameters

Comment: Nope, it was always like that. I'm not sure if I'm following why you're saying this: in any JS function you can pass less or more arguments than what the function expects. That function (`lastIndexOf`) expects 2 arguments, the first one being compulsory.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Default_parameters "In the past, the general strategy for setting defaults was to test parameter values in the function body and assign a value if they are undefined."

Comment: @PierreArlaud Thanks for the link, but, again, this has nothing to do with default parameters. Please check the edit, I believe that it explains the misunderstanding here. If it doesn't, I hope someone else can write the answer you seek. Best of luck to you.